# How to write a model spec to test PgSearch text_search query method (Rspec, Rails, Postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, pg-search

I'm trying to write a couple of tests in my model spec testing that the following method's logic works whether a query is passed in or not.

`models/payment.rb`

```
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, 
                  :against            => [:id, :transaction_id],
                  :using              => {:tsearch => {:prefix => true, :dictionary => "english"}},
                  :associated_against => {user: [:email, :name]}

  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      search(query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

and here is an example of the kind of test i'm trying to write, but blanking on the best way to accomplish this.

`/spec/models/payment_spec.rb`

```
describe '#text_search' do

  it "works when query is passed in" do
    payments = Payment.text_search(stub(:query))
    payments.should_not be_nil
    # is this even a good test??
  end

  it "still works if nothing is passed in" do
    payments = Payment.text_search(nil)
    payments.should_not be_nil
    # same here, does this spec test for anything helpful??
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you first need to decide what "works" mean when you say that you want to test whether the method "works" whether or not a query is provided.

If you want to do an actual search and check the results, then you don't need any test doubles, but you need to pass in a bona fide query for `search` to use and it would obviously be more effective to check that the results are exactly what you expected, as opposed to just not `nil`.

If you want to check that `search` and `scoped` are being called properly, they you can pass in a stub for a `query` and set expectations on `search` and `scoped` (e.g. that they're called and with what arguments). You can also provide a return value for each and check that the method returns that value.

You've got sort of a hybrid approach right now, at least with respect to the first example. You need to decide which direction to take things.

Hope that helps. If you need assistance constructing the actual code after deciding on the above and consulting the documentation, feel free to ask a follow-up question in the comments.